# Ajax update issues (SQL and extensions)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have an ajax update feature with some specific issues, I am sure this just needs some tweaking before it will work out 100%.

I will summarize the issues below as clearly as I can.

I have two files that interact with each other:

- **orders.php**
- **orders-claimed.vc.php**

my ajax is trying to update a table int value based on the button clicked. NO=0, YES=1, CANCELLED=2.

**orders.php**

- start of the page

  ```
      <?php
        session_start();
        require_once('orders-claimed.vc.php');
       ?>
  ```
- table column of the buttons:

  ```
                 <td data-target="scheduled">
                   <input id='userId' type='hidden'/>
                   <?php
                     if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 1) {
                    ?>

                    <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $rowOrder['orderid'] ;?>"><button class="btn-success">YES</button></a>

                   <?php
                 } else if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 0) {
                     ?>
                    <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $rowOrder['orderid'] ;?>"><button class="btn-danger">NO</button></a>
                   <?php
                 } else if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 2) {
                     ?>
                    <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $rowOrder['orderid'] ;?>"><button class="btn-warning">CANCELLED</button></a>
                   <?php
                     }
                    ?>
                 </td>
  ```
- modal used for interaction with the table

  ```
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content" style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
           <a href="#" id="update_yes" class="btn btn-success text-center center-block">YES</a><br>
           <a href="#" id="update_no" class="btn btn-danger text-center center-block">NO</a><br>
           <a href="#" id="update_cancelled" class="btn btn-warning text-center center-block">CANCEL</a>
         </div>

       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
  ```
- ajax code

  ```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

    //  append values in input fields
      $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){
            var id  = $(this).data('id');
            var scheduled  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text();

            $('#userId').val(id);
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
      });

      // now create event to get data from fields and update in database

      $('#update_no').click(function(){
         var id  = $('#userId').val();
         var scheduled = 0;

         $.ajax({
             url      : 'orders-claimed.vc.php',
             method   : 'post',
             data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
             success  : function(response){
                           // now update user record in table
                            $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').html('<a href="#"><button class="btn-danger">NO</button></a>');
                            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                        }
         });
      });

      $('#update_yes').click(function(){
         var id  = $('#userId').val();
         var scheduled = 1;

         $.ajax({
             url      : 'orders-claimed.vc.php',
             method   : 'post',
             data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
             success  : function(response){
                           // now update user record in table
                            $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').html('<a href="#"><button class="btn-success">YES</button></a>');
                            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                        }
         });
      });

      $('#update_cancelled').click(function(){
         var id  = $('#userId').val();
         var scheduled = 2;

         $.ajax({
             url      : 'orders-claimed.vc.php',
             method   : 'post',
             data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
             success  : function(response){
                           // now update user record in table
                            $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').html('<a href="#"><button class="btn-warning">CANCELLED</button></a>');
                            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                        }
         });
      }); }); 
   </script>
  ```

Note that all code above are all in the same file (orders.php)

- table column UI

[image: 1]

- modal

[image: modal]

- SQL table name "order"
  [image: 2]

these are my extensions in the page. most are being stored in a folder and are being linked.

```
   <script src="../_lib/v/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

   <script src="../_lib/v/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

   <script src="../_lib/v/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   <script src="../_lib/v/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>

   <script src="js/cms.js"></script>

   <link href="../_lib/v/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ajax does not function under slim.min.js and gets the "not a function error", so I changed it to the regular version of jquery from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js

**PROBLEM**

If I switch to the full version of jquery, the column updates but the session (the logged in user) ends and logs out automatically. Why is this happening?

---

My second problem is in the orders-claimed.vc.php file

**db.php**

```
<?php

class config_db {

  public function init() {
    $db = new PDO('*MY DATABASE DETAILS GO HERE*');

    date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');
    return $db;
  }

}

?>
```

**orders.claimed.vs.php**

- connecting to the database:

  ```
     $routePath = "../";

     require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
       $dbConfig = new config_db();
       $db = $dbConfig->init();
  ```
- SQL update

  ```
   if(isset($_POST['id'])){

    $orderid = $_POST['id'];
    $scheduled = $_POST['scheduled'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE order SET scheduled = '$scheduled' WHERE orderid = '$orderid'");
    $stmt->execute(); }
  ```

**PROBLEM**

the SQL code above does not update the table (the one shown in the screenshot, but ajax just updates the look of the button from the success functions (It goes back to its original value when the page refreshes). I would like to know what is the issue. It should be connecting to the buttons since it is using "if(isset($_POST['id']))".

I hope I have provided a clear explanation to my two problems, thank you for any help.

---

**UPDATE**
I used the following code below to check for an error on the button update:

```
console.log( 'scheduled: ' + scheduled + ' orderid: ' + $('#userId').val() );
```

when the button updates and the page refreshes that also logs out the session, i get the following error:

```
jquery-ui.js:1951 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'step' of undefined
    at String.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.js:1951)
    at each (jquery.slim.min.js:2)
    at Function.color.hook (jquery-ui.js:1913)
    at jquery-ui.js:1963
    at jquery-ui.js:2005
    at jquery-ui.js:14
    at jquery-ui.js:16
```

Comment: I couldn't find an HTML element with ID 'scheduled'. Can you point me where it is? And, with respect to your first problem, do you find any errors in your console when you inspect?

Comment: scheduled is used for data-target and a variable and there is no errors in my console in my first problem. the user just gets logged out.

Comment: No. when you say '#scheduled', it means that there is an HTML element with ID 'scheduled'. Do you have an element like that..??

Comment: my bad, forgot to take that out, that code is redundant. updated the question.

Comment: Can you add console.log( 'scheduled: ' + scheduled + '  orderid: ' + $('#userId').val() ) at the end of 'document.click on data-role update()' function, click on the button to display the modal and then inspect to see if you are getting the desired values to be passed to db?

Comment: tested your console.log and updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191632/discussion-between-sabhari-karthik-and-hadrian-clayton).

Comment: You should break this into two separate questions. You jquery and PHP issues are unrelated and therefore should be separate questions.

Comment: my php update is connected to my ajax though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have listed, I think that you might have "session_destroy()" somewhere in your php files (though it might not be put up here). Try commenting that out and see if the session ends or not. Hope it helps you :).